# Distinct Column in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to get a query result in HiveQL with one column as distinct. However the results are not matching . There are almost 20 columns in the table.

```
create table uniq_us row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' as select distinct(a),b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j from ctry_us_join;
```

**The resulting number of Rows :513238**

```
select count(distinct a) from ctry_us_join;
```

**The resulting number of rows : 151616**

How is this possible and is something wrong in my first or second query

Comment: Distinct is a keyword, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

U need to use subselect with group by statement.

```
select count(a) from (
select a, count(*) from ctry_us_join group by a) b
```

This is just one solution for this.

Comment: Thanks Dino. The problem is I want the result of first query with all the columns. Second query is just to check the authenticity of results.

Comment: Can you provide sample data from table and output which you want to get so we can write you query you want ?

Answer (score 0):

`Distinct` is a keyword, not a function. It applies to all columns you list in your `select` clause. It is quite reasonable that your table has only 151,616 distinct values in the column `a`, but multiple rows with the same value in the column `a` have different values in other columns. That might give you 513,238 distinct rows.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. So what is the solution to get the query results.

Comment: When you have two records with the same values in filed 'a' and different values in other fields, what values do you want in the new table?